# How to compare query text and list of buffers, using OpenEdge debugger?

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm working with appBuilder, procedure editor from OpenEdge Progress release 11.6.

Recently I've also started working with the OpenEdge Debugger, also version 11.6.

I have some troubles with the following lines of source code:

```
txt_Query = "FOR EACH Table1, ...".
...
handle_Query:SET-BUFFERS ("Table1", "Table2", ...).
...
handle_Query:QUERY-PREPARE(txt_Query).
```

The troubles are expressed by error message 7326, mentioning that the order of the buffers is wrong.

This means that the order of the tables, mentioned in `txt_Query` and `handle_Query:SET-BUFFERS()` is different.

I'd like to check the current order, using the debugger, but this is quite a burden, as, when viewing `handle_Query` in the dataview, I don't see the names of the buffers, but I see something like:

```
MemberBuffer(1) 1063
MemberBuffer(2) 1064
MemberBuffer(3) 1065
MemberBuffer(4) 1066
MemberBuffer(5) 1067
```

Does anybody know how to (easily) view this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you have the query-handle value, right-click an chose Dataview.

[image]

Then select MemberBuffer(1) and click on the View button.

Then navigate to the Name property

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should really consider moving to Developer Studio. That would make your life easier.

Right-click the object, select Dataview
[image]

Click each MemberBuffer. Click "View"

[image]

Select Name and click "Add watch"

[image]

Now you have the names in order in view

[image]

Demo program for this purpose:

```
DISPLAY "running".

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt NO-UNDO 
FIELD a AS INTEGER .

DEFINE TEMP-TABLE tt2 NO-UNDO 
FIELD a AS INTEGER.

DEFINE VARIABLE hQuery AS HANDLE NO-UNDO.

CREATE QUERY hQuery.

hQuery:SET-BUFFERS(BUFFER tt:HANDLE , BUFFER tt2:HANDLE).

READKEY.

// Error here...
hQuery:QUERY-PREPARE("for each tt2, each tt") .
```

Comment: Although your answer is very useful, upgrading to studio won't solve my issue, as the items to be put in the watch window are the same as the ones in the regular debugger (but there are plenty of other reasons to upgrade to the studio IDE :-) ).

Comment: @Dominique Agreed! This wouldn't be the major reason to move!